# HTTP Status 404 - /SignInProject/LoginServlet

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

It is showing Error after running these below codes on the Tomcat server.

The Error is :

```
- HTTP Status 404 - /SignInProject/LoginServlet
type Status report
message /SignInProject/LoginServlet
description The requested resource is not available.
```

Apache Tomcat/7.0.64

Can anyone please help me to fix this kind of error??

****LoginDao.java**

```
package com;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class LoginDao {
public static boolean validate(String name, String pass) {      
    boolean status = false;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "form";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("select * from login where user=? and password=?");
        pst.setString(1, name);
        pst.setString(2, pass);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        status = rs.next();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (pst != null) {
            try {
                pst.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

}**

**LoginServlet.java**

```
package comm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.LoginDao;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
        throws ServletException, IOException {  

    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

    String n=request.getParameter("username");  
    String p=request.getParameter("userpass"); 

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session!=null)
    session.setAttribute("name", n);

    if(LoginDao.validate(n, p)){  
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");  
        rd.forward(request,response);  
    }  
    else{  
        out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password
    error</p>");  
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");  
        rd.include(request,response);  
    }  

    out.close();  
}
```

}

**index.jsp**

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Login Application</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
    <fieldset style="width: 300px">
        <legend> Login to App </legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" required="required"   
   /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="userpass" 
    required="required" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h3>Login successful!!!</h3>
<h4>
    Hello,
    <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you map the servlet in your web.xml?

Comment: Sir, can you please help me how to map the servlet in web.xml??